# Get-WmiObject win32 classes only?

Tags: powershell, wmi

In PowerShell you can use the Get-WmiObject cmdlet to grab WMI classes.

I have noticed that I can only gain access to [win32 classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), can I gain access in PowerShell to any other classes besides the win32_*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
get-wmiobject -list
```

Will give a list of available classes on your machine.  Is that what you were asking?

You can also supply a namespace with the `-namespace` parameter to list the classes in other namespaces besides `root\CIMV2`